# Qt C++ - QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qgraphicsscene

Возвращаюсь к сортировкам и Qt. Пытаюсь реализовать некоторое подобие sound-of-sorting от panthema. У меня есть сцена QtGraphics, на которой я вывел белые прямоугольники, которые визуализируют массив
[image: Внешний вид программы]

Реализовал класс, в котором будут лежать все сортировки и который будет посылать нужные мне сигналы во время работы сортировки в отдельном потоке:

```
class DemoSortWorker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void compared(size_t, size_t);
    void accessed(size_t);
    void swapped(size_t, size_t);
    void finished();
public:
    DemoSortWorker();
    void bubble_sort(ArraySequence<int>&, int (*) (int, int), size_t);
    void shaker_sort(ArraySequence<int>&, int (*) (int, int), size_t);
};
```

Сортировка:

```
void DemoSortWorker::bubble_sort(ArraySequence<int>& sq, int (*cmp) (int, int), size_t speed) {
    emit accessed(1);
    for (size_t i = sq.length() - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j != i; ++j) {
            emit compared(j, j + 1);
            thread()->msleep(10000/speed);
            emit accessed(2);
            if (cmp(sq[j], sq[j + 1]) > 0) {
                std::swap(sq[j], sq[j + 1]);
                emit accessed(2);
                emit swapped(j, j + 1);
                thread()->msleep(10000/speed);
            }
        }
    }
    emit finished();
}
```

Слипы нужны для регулировки скорости сортировки ну и для того, чтобы визуализация успевала (если есть идеи по поводу того как это "сделать быстрее и лучше", то я не против)
Ну и слот на клик по кнопке start:

```
void SortVisualization::on_runButton_clicked()
{
    ui->runButton->setEnabled(false);
    ui->speedSlider->setEnabled(false);
    ui->sizeSlider->setEnabled(false);
    ui->sortingsListWidget->setEnabled(false);
    ui->typeComboBox->setEnabled(false);
    thread = new QThread;
    worker = new DemoSortWorker;
    void (DemoSortWorker::*sort)(ArraySequence<int>&, int(*)(int, int), double);
    connect(thread, &QThread::started, worker, [&]() {
        if (ui->sortingsListWidget->currentItem()->text() == "Пузырьковая сортировка") worker->bubble_sort(array, [](int a, int b) {return a - b;}, ui->speedSlider->value());
        /*потом допишу другие или мб придумаю как это лучше сделать*/
    });
    connect(worker, &DemoSortWorker::accessed, [&](size_t inc) {
        QString text = ui->accessCount->text();
        ui->accessCount->setText(QString::number(text.toInt() + inc));
    });
    connect(worker, &DemoSortWorker::compared, [&](size_t i, size_t j) {
        QString text = ui->cmpCount->text();
        ui->cmpCount->setText(QString::number(text.toInt() + 1));
        if (compared.first != -1) {
            rectangles[compared.first]->setBrush(Qt::white);
            rectangles[compared.second]->setBrush(Qt::white);
        }
        compared.first = i;
        compared.second = j;
        rectangles[compared.first]->setBrush(Qt::green);
        rectangles[compared.second]->setBrush(Qt::green);
    });
    connect(worker, &DemoSortWorker::swapped, [&](size_t i, size_t j) {
        QString text = ui->swapCount->text();
        ui->swapCount->setText(QString::number(text.toInt() + 1));
        rectangles[i]->setRect(i*(scene->width()/array.length()), scene->height() - array[i]*(scene->height()/array.length()), scene->width()/array.length(), scene->height() + 5);
        rectangles[i]->setBrush(Qt::white);
        rectangles[j]->setRect(j*(scene->width()/array.length()), scene->height() - array[j]*(scene->height()/array.length()), scene->width()/array.length(), scene->height() + 5);
        rectangles[j]->setBrush(Qt::white);
    });
    connect(worker, &DemoSortWorker::finished, thread, &QThread::quit);
    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, [&](){
        ui->runButton->setEnabled(true);
        ui->speedSlider->setEnabled(true);
        ui->sizeSlider->setEnabled(true);
        ui->sortingsListWidget->setEnabled(true);
        ui->typeComboBox->setEnabled(true);
        thread->deleteLater();
        worker->deleteLater();
    });
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();
}
```

В чём собственно проблема:

1. Если элементы, которые сейчас сравниваются успешно перекрашиваются в зелёный, как и надо, то элементы, которые свапаются просто пропадают (и дело не в том, что я делаю по-уродски через setRect)
2. Причина первого скорее всего кроется в предупреждениях дебаггера: `QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread`. Смысл предупреждения понятен, но не понятна причина.

Хочу, чтобы помогли разобраться где я налажал. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: 2. Объект таймера, созданный в одном потоке, не может стартовать из другого. Но вот где он?

Comment: @Alexander Chernin
Я не использовал таймеры, в этом вся соль. Единственное тут, что связано с таймерами это sleep

Answer (score 0):

а если вместо

```
thread()->msleep(10000/speed)
```

использовать статическую

```
QThread::msleep(10000/speed)
```

или даже лучше не морозить поток, а делать сравнение элементов по таймеру (примерный код):
При инициализации private переменные объекта (i,j,sq), переданные на вход и стартовать таймер

```
i = sq.length() - 1;
j = 0;
this->sq = sq;
conect(&timer,&QTimer::timeout(),this,&DemoSortWorker::timerTimeout);
timer.setSingleShot(false);
timer.setInterval(10000/speed);
timer.start();
```

и сравнивать поэлементно в слоте по таймеру

```
DemoSortWorker::timerTimeout(){
   mutex.lock(); // или timer.stop()
   if(i > 0) { i-=1;
   }else{ i=sq.length() - 1;j+=1;}
   if(i==j){
     timer.stop();
     emit finished();
   }
   emit compared(j, j + 1);
   if (cmp(sq[j], sq[j + 1]) > 0) {
      //.....
   }
   mutex.unlock(); // или timer.start(); тогда такты будут = заданная скорость+скорость обработки одной итерации
}
```

Comment: QTimer::msleep не помог. А с таймерами не очень понял. Т.е. предлагаете просто реализацию сортировки на timerTimeout перенести? А как это вообще тогда будет работать, если в форе будет вызываться таймер быстрее чем он успевает закончить отсчёт?

Comment: можете использовать QMutex для синхронизации обработки, или тормозить на время обработки таймер (в ответе для примера добавил синхронизацию мьютексом)

Comment: Так mutex же просто запрещает выполнять какие-либо действия в других потоках, пока происходит данное. Но это же вроде не решает проблему, т.е. условно говоря на первой итерации таймер стартанет, действия произойдут, таймер ещё не успеет отсчитать нужное время, уже следующая итерация начнётся и таймер снова стартанёт. Или я чего-то не понимаю

Comment: mutex.lock() блокирует дальнейшее выполнение именно в слоте, если он будет вызван повторно. если мьютекс уже заблокирован, он будет дожидаться его разблокировки